# React flow error inner render method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

`EDIT:`
 I added `React.Element<*>` as return type , and return `<View />`instead of null, but there is still same error.

And My flow version is 0.53.1

```
render() {
   return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
       <TabHeader title={strings.tabBarLabelRecommend} />
       {this._renderVideoCategory()}
     </View>
   );
}
```

Above is my render method, and _renderVideoCategory is :

```
_renderVideoCategory = (): React.Element<*> => {
  if (!this.props.recommendVideos.length) {
    return <View />;
  }
   this.tabWidth = C.SCREEN_WIDTH / this.props.recommendVideos.count;
   return (
     <TabViewAnimated style={{ flex: 1 }} 
       navigationState={this.state} 
       renderScene={this._renderScene}
       renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
       renderPager={this._renderPager}
       onRequestChangeTab={this._handleChangeTab}
     />
   );
};
```

But flow shows an error :(The line 150 is `{this._renderVideoCategory()}`)

`Error:(150, 10) Flow: exact type: object type. This type is incompatible with union: undefined | null | boolean | number | string | type application of type React$Element | type application of identifier Iterable`

Comment: This is not relevant to your answer. Now I am learning React-Native, and I didn't find any good site for this, can you share if you know any good site and all in one place?

Comment: can you precise where is the line 150 in your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning **null** return an empty div

```
if (this.props.recommendVideos.length === 0) {
    return <View/>;
}
```

**EDIT**

Could you make a change to the way you are declaring the function as

```
_renderVideoCategory (): React.Element<*>{
    if (this.props.recommendVideos.length === 0) {
        return <View/>;
    }
    this.tabWidth = C.SCREEN_WIDTH / this.props.recommendVideos.count;
    return (
        <TabViewAnimated
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              navigationState={this.state}
              renderScene={this._renderScene}
              renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
              renderPager={this._renderPager}
              onRequestChangeTab={this._handleChangeTab}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: @yifan_z what is there on line 150?

Comment: {this._renderVideoCategory()}

Comment: I added React.Element<*> as return type , and return <View />instead of null, but there is still same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152643/discussion-between-shubham-jain-and-yifan-z).

Answer (score 1):

Try returning an empty view since Flow expects you returning a React.Element (annotated in the example code too):

```
_renderVideoCategory = ():React.Element<*> => {
  if (!this.props.recommendVideos.length) {
    return <View />;
  }

  this.tabWidth = C.SCREEN_WIDTH / this.props.recommendVideos.count;

  return (
  <TabViewAnimated
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    navigationState={this.state}
    renderScene={this._renderScene}
    renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
    renderPager={this._renderPager}
    onRequestChangeTab={this._handleChangeTab}
  />);
}
```